# Chrome: Display address bar when starting an application shortcut

Tags: google-chrome, display-settings

When I start Chrome through an application shortcut, the address bar, extensions buttons and bookmark buttons are hidden. Is there a way to show them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fom Chrome's website [Help](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95710)

When you double-click a shortcut icon, the website opens in a special streamlined window that doesn't display tabs, buttons, the address bar, or menus. Many of the browser functions are available instead in the menu that appears when you click the page logo in the upper-right corner of the window.

This design is a purposeful setting. If you wish to open pages with the address bar, extensions etc then use it as a favourite in a normal browser window.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually I was expecting some way to override the default behavior but there is nothing to do if this is purposefully prevented. However, I don't agree with the design decision because Chrome plugins are actually part of the Chrome application from the user's point of view.

Comment: @Mert Nuhoglu I aggree. In the review I read of Chromes application Shortcuts this was the one major downside to them that the author picked up on. Once you get used to using an extension or plugin having it 'not there anymore' can be really frustrating.

Comment: Yes, having the ability to show the address bar in application shortcuts would be incredibly valueable.